# Toggling row colors

Tags: jquery

I have a table cell in the footer that allows the user to turn on row coloring:

```
$('#highlight').click(function() {
$(this).parents('table').RowColors();
})

// From Chapter 7 of Learning jQuery
$.fn.RowColors = function() {
$('tbody tr:odd', this).removeClass('even').addClass('odd');
$('tbody tr:even', this).removeClass('odd').addClass('even');
return this;
};
```

Q: How do I write a selector that says: IF there is at least 1 row with class="even", then remove both "even" and "odd" ELSE execute the RowColors function.

Comment: I don't really understand the last part of this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advice would be to do it slightly differently. Have just one class with the default state being the other. So:

```
tr td { background: yellow; }
tr.odd td { background: blue; }
```

and then this is as simple as:

```
$("tr").toggleClass("odd");
```

or more specifically:

```
$("tbody > tr").removeClass("odd").filter(":nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
```

**Note:** avoid using `:odd` and `:even`. They usually don't mean what you think they mean. `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` tend to be what you really mean.

I would probably write something like:

```
$("#highlight").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("table").children("tbody").children("tr").removeClass("odd")
    .filter(":nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
  return false;
});
```

Put it into a separate function if you wish.

**Edit:** to check whether something is empty:

```
var odd = $(".odd");
if (odd.length == 0) {
  // do one thing
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

jQuery objects support the `length` property and the `size()` method, which do the same thing.

Comment: Cletus: I like where this is going.  I need to be able to toggle the highlighting, such that if there is already a tr class="odd", then removeClass odd, else addClass odd.

Comment: Oh I see where I'm not communicating correctly.  What I mean by toggle is that there is no styling, or the odd rows are styled.

Comment: How do you write an IF/THEN statement in JavaScript and jQuery?
If I have a selector such as $('.odd'), and it returns _something_, then how do I check to see that it returned _something_, and not _nothing_?

Answer (score 1):

Alternating row colors can be done with pure CSS (as long as you don't need to support IE6/7):

```
tr { background-color: green; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: red; }
```

Comment: "as long as you don't need to support IE6/7" ...is there ANYBODY that lucky?

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery plug-in called [Colorize](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Colorize) that already does this. You could use it, or check out the code?